# Ruby/Rails, appending hash to array which belongs to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have this situation:

```
skeleton = 
{
        "timeline" => 
        { 
            "data" => []
        }
}

template = 
{
        "A" => "",
        "B" => "",
        "C" => "",
}
```

From the controller I make a query which returns me an array of hashes:

```
@cdr = Cdr.select("start, end, clid")
```

then I iterate over the array and set the "template" hash fields and in the last step I append this hash to an array which belongs to "skeleton" hash:

```
@cdr.each do |cdr|
        template["A"] = cdr.start
        template["B"] = cdr.end
        template["C"] = cdr.clid
        skeleton["timeline"]["data"] << template
    end
```

so to expected result is:

```
skeleton = 
{
        "timeline" => 
        { 
            "data" => [
               {
               "A" => "sample1",
               "B" => "sample2",
               "C" => "sample3",
               },
               {
               "A" => "sample4",
               "B" => "sample5",
               "C" => "sample6",
               }
            ]
        }
}
```

but the real result I'm getting is:

```
skeleton = 
{
        "timeline" => 
        { 
            "data" => [
               {
               "A" => "sample1",
               "B" => "sample2",
               "C" => "sample3",
               },
               {
               "A" => "sample1",
               "B" => "sample2",
               "C" => "sample3",
               }
            ]
        }
}
```

all entries in the array contain same data. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new template array through each cycle through. I don't think you can change the value of the key while it is being used as a key.

```
@cdr.each do |cdr|
    temp_inst = template.clone
    temp_inst["A"] = cdr.start
    temp_inst["B"] = cdr.end
    temp_inst["C"] = cdr.clid
    skeleton["timeline"]["data"] << temp_inst
end
```